# Valid annotation not working for Object if with MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Why is `@Valid` annotation not working for my domain model if there is `MultipartFile`? I have the following codes in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public String create(@Valid Game game, MultipartFile[] screenshotFiles, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "game/create";
    }
     // others lines removed for brevity
}
```

I put breakpoints to debug in the method signature as well as `bindingResult.hasErrors` but I can't debug it. Right after submit, it doesn't reach `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())` but it is quick to display `Whitelabel Error Page` with:

```
Validation failed for object='game'. Error count: 1
```

It is working if `MultipartFile` is not included. Just to be clear, I'm not validating the `MultipartFile` but the `Game` object. I have seen some questions which seem to be similar to this but they are validating the `MultipartFile` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method signature to:

```
public String create(@Valid Game game, BindingResult bindingResult, MultipartFile[] screenshotFiles)
```

Validation result argument should go after the argument being validated.

From spring reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args):

> Data binding can result in errors. By default, a `BindException` is raised. However, to check for such errors in the controller method, you can add a `BindingResult` argument immediately next to the `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: Wow! It works like a charm. Thank you so much for this. I'm overwhelmed by this solution. God bless!

Comment: I just realize  now that it is not @Valid that is not working but the BindingResult.

Comment: @JulezJupiter yes, it is. The `errors` were not for `game`. "I put breakpoints to debug in the method signature as well as `bindingResult.hasErrors()` but I can't debug it. Right after submit, it doesn't reach `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())` but it is quick to display Whitelabel Error Page" Spring threw `BindException` assuming that in this method you don't want to know about `game` validation errors occurred

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Quite helpful.